# In Android, how to shift a bitmap?

Tags: android

I am trying, unsuccessfully, to "shift" a bitmap.  By "shift", I mean:  if I have a 500x300 and I shift it 50 pixels to the right, the result should be a 500x300 bitmap where every pixel has been shifted 50 pixels to the left, and the 50 right most pixels are blank.  So, the new image is the same as the old one except the left side is cropped, and a blank area is appended to the right side.  The below code successfully crops the left side, but it does not produce a blank area on the right side, it just produces a narrower bitmap:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(oldBitmap.getWidth(), m_CurrentBitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(oldBitmap.getWidth(), deltaX, 0, oldBitmap.getWidth() - deltaX, oldBitmap.getHeight());
```

So then I tried creating a new Bitmap with the desired dimensions, and manually setting the pixels (with an offset).  However, this still produces a narrower Bitmap, lacking the blank area on the right side:

```
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(oldBitmap.getWidth(), oldBitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

int[] oldPixels = new int[(int)(oldBitmap.getWidth() - deltaX) * oldBitmap.getHeight()];
            m_CurrentBitmap.getPixels(oldPixels, 0, (int) (oldBitmap.getWidth() - deltaX), (int)deltaX, 0, (int) (oldBitmap.getWidth() - deltaX), oldBitmap.getHeight());

newBitmap.setPixels(oldPixels, 0,  (int) (oldBitmap.getWidth() - deltaX), 0, 0, (int) (oldBitmap.getWidth() - deltaX), oldBitmap.getHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Okay, so you basically want to draw the following of the old bitmap onto the new bitmap.

You need to draw from the `OldBitmap` pixels from `deltaX` to `OldBitmap.Width` onto the `NewBitmap` pixels from `0` to `NewBitmap.width` - `deltaX`.  This should leave a right margin of the NewBitmap (`NewBitmap.Width` - `deltaX` to `NewBitmap.Width`) blank (assuming that the canvas behind it is white or whatever "blank" color is).

Comment: if i use deltaX as an offset, then any width > oldBitmap.getWidth() - deltaX will give an outOfBounds exception.

Comment: @ab11 I updated my response with at least the math portion, let me know if it doesn't make sense ;)  I'm not sure how to exactly translate drawing only a certain segment of a bitmap onto another in code because I haven't done it before.